# How to disable charge waiting time Alcate 9024w

Tags: battery, charging, stock-android

My Alcatel A30 tablet 9024w is a great tablet but it has this issue. If i let my tablet die it will be 20 minutes of charging until i can use it again. I would like to disable this self-imposed limitation.

And btw, I know there's gonna be that one huy who's like, "isn't that bad for the battery if you do that?" And I am going to say right now, **I dont care**.

(Sorry if i come off a bit harsh)